# Powershell output insert into remote database server ERROR

Tags: sql, powershell, connection

I use the following command to connect to remote database:

```
    $SQLServer = "Servername" 
    $SQLDBName = "DBname"
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID= username; Password= password" 
    $SqlConnection.Open()
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Tablename(ReceivedTime, Subject)VALUES($time, $subject)"
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
```

But have the following err message:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance  name is correct and that SQL Server is configured
>   to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error:
>   40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)" At line:10 char:1
>
> - $conn.Open()
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

I need to connect to the remote server and online solutions mainly focus on the local servers, so they are not suitable for me. (Company server/database and network, maybe different from local server?)

Hope you can help me improve the code or provide with some solutions. Thanks all.

Comment: Looks like your connection string is not good. Can you try to make it work with Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: YOu are not able to connect to the sql server from the system where you are running the script. Could you please try to connecting normally and see if at all its working

Comment: I would like you to check 2 things. One is if the server is having any instance. second, try with windows authentication and see, then the connection string should be like this`$Connection.ConnectionString ="server=.;database=mydatabase;trusted_connection=true;"`

Comment: You didn't specify which remote database you are using

Comment: Thank you all for your reply.

Comment: The database has been used for a long time and my colleagues successfully connected to databases by C#. So I think maybe I missed something in my scripts. I cannot connect to local server because i don't have the local server.

Comment: I have already use the code below to specify the database and needed information: $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID= username; Password= password"